# "Submit for review" for updates on existing posts

Tags: custom-post-types, user-roles, capabilities, publish

My custom user group for proofreaders has access to all our posts and pages but can't create or publish new ones. I also want disallow them to publish their changes.

As far as I know, Wordpress has no bulit in functionality to force a *Submit for review* on updates.
As some of our articles contain small code snippets (bootstrap alerts, tags, tables, etc...), it would be great if an administrator has to review the changes before publishing them so that code errors, that may have occured while correcting typos, could be fixed before they are published. Furthermore the proofreaders – which are people outside of our group – could not delete or add content of the article.

How could I achieve this behaviour?